# How can I loop through all nodes in all paths?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops, recursion, nodes

I have an array which has got 4 members, I need to try all loop combinations like

```
0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 2
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3
0 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3
0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1
0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
0 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2
```

This will lead to 6 different results, then I will compare those results and find the best one. I wasted my hours and hours to do that recursive loop but I could not made it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by loop, but what you call "all paths" is commonly known as "permutations". Try searching with that keyword, there are tons of related question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all path by using some brute force algorithms . But brute force algorithms are slow and takes so much times. Instead of brute force you can use dynamic programming which increase speed and decrees times. Traveling salesman is not the same problem as yours but it gives you the main idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use DFS to visit the nodes in the graph as follows :

```
DFS(i,path) {

  visited[i] = true
  neighbours = cal_neighbours(i)
  has_valid_neighbour = false
  for n in neighbours {
     if(!visited[n]) {
         DFS(n,path+"->"+n)
         has_valid_neighbour = true
     }
  }
  if(!has_valid_neighbour) {
     print(path)      
  }
  visited[i] = false
}
```

**Call : DFS(0,"0");**